# Handling CSVs with poor consistency in their construction in Python

Tags: python, csv

Using CSV to take in and process a file that I have little control over from multiple sources. The issue here is that the origin process of the file may double quote all fields, single quote all fields, or use no quotes. The other challenge here is some data fields may contain single quotes/apostrophes, double quotes, or commas inside quotes which I have to replace with a space.

CSV Reader gives me the ability to set up through dialog a quote character, but it may be different from one file to another.

Two fields, ID String cannot contain any quotes and they must be stripped and name string which may contain quotes.

It could be:

id123, drill bit - 1/4", otherField1

or

1d234, "10' Pole", otherField1

or

id345, box of monkeys, otherField1

or

"id456", "ham sandwich, stale", "otherField1"

So the big issue is I can handle any one of these with the CSV reader by itself, but how can I handle all of them?

I know the obvious answer is to get my DeLorean up to 88mph and stop the system that lead to this level of insanity, but who knows where we will get enough juice?

Answer (score 0):

With your exact examples as `case1.csv`:

```
id123, drill bit - 1/4", otherField1
1d234, "10' Pole", otherField1
id345, box of monkeys, otherField1
"id456", "ham sandwich, stale", "otherField1"
```

And your comment example as `case2.csv`:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
foo, ltest, 'l,test', ltest
```

The following uses the `Sniffer` class to detect the csv dialect:

```
import csv
for file in ('case1.csv','case2.csv'):
    with open(file,newline='') as f:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
        f.seek(0)
        r = csv.reader(f,dialect)
        for line in r:
            print(line)
```

Output:

```
['id123', 'drill bit - 1/4"', 'otherField1']
['1d234', "10' Pole", 'otherField1']
['id345', 'box of monkeys', 'otherField1']
['id456', 'ham sandwich, stale', 'otherField1']
['id123', 'drill bit - 1/4"', 'otherField1']
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['foo', 'ltest', 'l,test', 'ltest']
```

You may have to adjust the size of the `.read()` for the Sniffer in case the beginning of some files doesn't have quoted fields in the first 1000 bytes or so.  That's what happens when you have to guess.

Comment: With that code the lines:

1,2,3,4
foo, ltest, 'l,test', ltest, ltest

get me:

OrderedDict([('1', 'foo'), ('2', 'ltest'), ('3', "'l"), ('4', "test'"), (None, ['ltest', 'ltest'])])

when it should be 3: l,test

Comment: @Wes If you have other test cases edit your question and list them in the examples. I did state "with your exact examples" (expecting they were incomplete) and you asked after your examples "How can I handle all of [the examples]".  That said, there is a Sniffer class that can guess and the settings of a particular .csv file.  I'll add your new test case and see if I can make a working example.